# Signle Table strategy Inheritance in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am going to make a simple inheritance in hibernate by using three simple `Person` , `Teacher` and `Student` classes.

Here is my parent class (`Person.java`)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Person Type" , discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

My `Teacher.java` Class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Teacher")
public class Teacher extends Person implements Serializable {

    private String teacherDegree;

    public String getTeacherDegree() {
        return teacherDegree;
    }

    public void setTeacherDegree(String teacherDegree) {
        this.teacherDegree = teacherDegree;
    }
}
```

And my `Student.java` class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Student")
public class Student extends Person implements Serializable {

    private String studentCollege;

    public String getStudentCollege() {
        return studentCollege;
    }

    public void setStudentCollege(String studentCollege) {
        this.studentCollege = studentCollege;
    }
}
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
...
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.abc.Person"/>
        <mapping class="com.abc.Teacher"/>
        <mapping class="com.abc.Student"/>
...
```

Tester Class:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher();

    teacher2.setName("Teacher ABC"); // person property
    teacher2.setAddress("NewYork"); // person property
    teacher2.setTeacherDegree("phd"); // teacher property

    session.save(teacher2);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

But i got this error:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Type) values ('NewYork', 'Teacher ABC', 'phd', 'Teacher')' at line 1
```

Comment: Not sure you have the right (depending on your underlying database) to have a discriminator column name with a space.

Comment: you can also use hibernate property to show sql, which makes debugging easier..<property name="show_sql">true</property>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also as a convention, you should go with the following style. I do not recall at the moment, but I think you need some sort of escaping for white space in column names.

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PERSON_TYPE" , discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
```

Sometimes it makes life easier to comply with most of the community's coding habits.